# How to derive the cosets of $A_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

In the alternating group $A_4$ for the subgroup of $H\le A_4$ find all of its left and right cosets where $$H=\{\text{Id},(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}.$$

We have by Lagrange's theorem that $$|A_4:H|=\frac{|A_4|}{|H|}=\frac{24/2}{3}=4$$ which means that $H$ has $4$ left and $4$ right cosets.

By definition a left coset of $H$ in $A_4$ determined by $x\in A_4$ is the set $\{xh:h\in H\}$.

So, the left cosets will be $x\text{Id},x(1,2,3),x(1,3,2)$, right?

How can I find the $4$th coset?

Comment: What do you mean by "the 4th"?  Did you find $3$ already?

Comment: $x\text{Id},x(1,2,3),x(1,3,2)$ are the first three left cosets, right?

Comment: No, those are three elements, and which element is "$x$" supposed to be?

Comment: Or, do you mean to say that the set 
$$
\{x(1,2,3) \mid x \in A_4\}
$$
is one of the cosets of $H$? Because this too is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Because this is not the definition of a coset.  A coset of $H$ is a set of the form
$$
xH = \{xh \mid h \in H\}
$$
where $x$ is a fixed element of $A_4$.  Note, importantly, that we can have $x \neq y$, but $xH = yH$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okay, so is $\text{Id}H$ a left coset of H?

Comment: yes, so one of the cosets of $H$ is the set $H$ itself.  There are four other cosets.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom three other cosets?

Comment: @JackBauer Right; four cosets in total, so three other cosets.  How did you come across this question almost 3 years later, by the way?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I was looking up the answer to this problem which I was working on.

Comment: @JackBauer fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the 100% way to do this is get every element of $A_4$ multiply it to left and right of $H$ to get your $aH$ and $Hb$. I will answer to answer how to come up with the selection of elements to get 4 left cosets *and* 4 right cosets.

I am copying the listing of $A_4$ by johnny09 posted in his or her answer, but with a rearrangement for emphasizing certain elements: $$A_4=\{\text{Id},$$

$$(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,3,4),(2,4,3),(1,2,4),(1,4,2),(1,3,4),(1,4,3)$$

$$(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}$$

Looking at $A_4$ this way, we have 3 to cosets derive because $H$ is its own coset, and we also have 3 elements other than the identity that are not like the others (We can also say we have 4 cosets to derive and 4 elements that are not like the others). I am going to base my selection of elements on these 3 elements.

A permutation property is: $$(a,b)(c,d)=(adc)(abc)$$

From this, we can write:

$$(1,2)(3,4) = (143)(123) \tag{1}$$

$$(1,3)(2,4) = (142)(132) \tag{2}$$

$$(1,4)(2,3) = (132)(142) \tag{3}$$

A permutation property is: $$(a,b)(c,d)=(dba)(dca)$$

From this, we can write:

$$(1,2)(3,4) = (421)(431) \tag{4}$$

$$(1,3)(2,4) = (431)(421) \tag{5}$$

$$(1,4)(2,3) = (341)(321) \tag{6}$$

My selection for $a$ to derive left cosets $aH$ will be based on $(1),(2),(6)$

$$a = 1, (143), (142), (341)$$

My selection for $b$ to derive right cosets $Hb$ is the reverse of $(1),(2),(6)$:

$$(1,2)(3,4) = (143)(123) \tag{1}$$

$$(1,3)(2,4) = (142)(132) \tag{2}$$

$$(1,4)(2,3) = (341)(321) \tag{6}$$

$$(1,2)(3,4) = (321)(341) \tag{1(rev)}$$

$$(1,3)(2,4) = (231)(241) \tag{2(rev)}$$

$$(1,4)(2,3) = (123)(143) \tag{6(rev)}$$

I select $$b = 1, (341), (241), (143)$$

To prove that my choices for a work, I used the property: $(a,b,c)(c,b,e)=(abe)$. Other permutation properties are: $(a,b)(c,d)=(cda)(cba)=(acd)(abd)=(dab)(dcb)$. For b, see: [Why did this reversal from the left cosets of $\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle$ in $A_4$ give me the right cosets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952359/why-did-this-reversal-from-the-left-cosets-of-langle-1-2-3-rangle-in-a)

---

For a systematic approach (but still aiming for the products of disjoint transposition), we could try to solve $(1,2)(3,4)=(123)(abc)$, $(1,2)(3,4)=(132)(abc)$ and also for the others.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $$A_4=\{\text{Id},(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,4,3),(2,3,4),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4,2),(1,4,3),(1,4)(2,3)\}$$
We have,
\begin{align}
(1,2)(3,4)\cdot(1,2,3)=(2,4,3)\\
(1,3)(2,4)\cdot(1,2,3)=(1,4,2)\\
(1,4)(2,3)\cdot(1,2,3)=(1,3,4)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(1,2)(3,4)\cdot(1,3,2)=(1,4,3)\\
(1,3)(2,4)\cdot(1,3,2)=(2,3,4)\\
(1,4)(2,3)\cdot(1,3,2)=(1,2,4)
\end{align}
So the left cosets of $H$ are $\text{Id}H,(1,2)(3,4)H,(1,3)(2,4)H,(1,4)(2,3)H$.

We have to repeat the above calculations for $Hx$ (right coset).