# Why did this reversal from the left cosets of $\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle$ in $A_4$ give me the right cosets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

In this question [How to derive the cosets of $A_4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657355/how-to-derive-the-cosets-of-a-4/2952340#2952340)

I derived that the left cosets are $$\{ 1\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle, (143)\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle, (142)\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle, (341)\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle \}$$ I derived the right cosets $$\{ \langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle 1, \langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle (341), \langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle (241), \langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle (143) \}$$ by simply reversing $$a = 1, (143), (142), (341)$$ to get $$b = 1, (341), (241), (143)$$

I think this has to do with properties of conjugation, cosets or subgroups or normal subgroups, but I don't know which. I think $\langle (1, 2, 3) \rangle$ is not normal because the cosets don't correspond.

---

Remark based on Nicky Hekster's answer: I didn't realize it sooner! $(1, 2, 3)$ is simply $x$ in $S_3$ whose inverse is $x^2$ in both $S_3$ and in $S_4$ (and in $S_n, n\ge 3$ or even $n = 1,2$ if you want to be vacuous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if $H \leq G$, $|G:H|=n$, then a set  $\{g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_n\}$ represents the *left* cosets of $H$ if and only if  $\{g_1^{-1}, g_2^{-1}, \cdots, g_n^{-1}\}$ represents the *right* cosets of $H$. This is easy to prove. And remember, writing a cycle from right to left gives you the inverse of this same cycle.

Comment: Thank you Nicky Hekster!

Comment: You are welcome!!